# Como mudo o local da importação dos módulos no python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import pygame
```

[image: O programa da esse erro, dizendo que não tem nenhum modulo]
O programa da esse erro, dizendo que não tem nenhum modulo

[image: Só funciona quando mostro o local para o programa:]
Só funciona quando mostro o local para o programa

Estou iniciando meu estudos na linguagem.
Meu python e vscode estão instalado no disco D:, não estou entendo pq os módulos estão sendo importados no disco C:.
Gostaria de mudar o local da importação, para não ficar mostrando todo vez o local do arquivo

Comment: quantas versões do python estão  instaladas ?

Comment: Duas, uma que eu instalei no disco D: e outra que foi instalada pelo aplicativo da microsoft Store no disco C:

Comment: pode ter acontecido que as instalações estão vinculadas a instalação no C e não ao D. Tera que especificar qual versão sera usada no IDE. como vscode pode criar mv para gerenciar a versão em uso. como esta o path, esta para a versão que quer usar ?

Comment: nas opções do vscode. File Preferences Settings ..  escolhe qual interprete do python sera usando.. só procurar "python" e a opção "Default Interpreter Path
Path to Python, you can use a custom version of Python by modifying this setting to include the full path."

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema. Muito obrigado

Comment: Nas próximas perguntas, evite colocar código ou dados como imagens. Isso impede a busca no site, impede que pessoas possam copiar e colar trechos do seu código como exemplo, e atrapalha mais um monte de coisas.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que aprender sobre "virtual environments": são um recurso usado pela linguagem para cada projeto ter suas próprias bibliotecas, sem que haja problemas de conflitos no sistema.

Assim, se você tem um jogo que depende do pygame 1.8, e outro que depende do pygame 2.0, pode ter os dois instalados no PC.

Além disso, usando os virtualenvs, todas as dependencias do projeto são encontradas automaticamente.

Em geral as IDEs e editores mais avançados, como o vscode oferecem suporte a virtualenv - mas claro, é um mecanismo que não depende de IDEs - apenas da linguagem, e pode ser ativado via terminal, ou especificado em um atalho pra rodar seu programa, se criar um link pra ele rodar direto.

O que um virtualenv faz é colocar cópias e atalhos para o Python e as bibliotecas do sistema dentro de uma pasta - que em geral mantemos junto com o projeto (mas pode ficar em qualquer lugar). Antes de trabalhar com o projeto, ou executar ele, "ativamos" o virtualenv. Aí, você instala qualquer dependencia do seu projeto direto dentro do virtualenv (mesmo se já tiver instalado no Python do sistema, instale de novo). Depois, conforme você for entendendo dos projetos, especifica essa dependência nos arquivos de configuração do próprio projeto - assim, o Python pode instalar automaticamente as dependencias pra qualquer pessoa que for instalar o seu projeto.

Para fazer na linha de comando: abra o computador, e vá com o cmd até a pasta do seu projeto (com o comando "cd"). Chegando lá, digite `python -m venv env` - o Python vai criar uma pasta "env" com tudo lá dentro. Na sequencia, ative o virtualenv: `env\scripts\activate.bat` no Windows ou  `source env\bin\activate` no Linux/Mac.  Aí pode digitar `pip install pygame` que ele será instalado.

Paa trabalhar com virtuaenv no vscode, tem um guia aqui: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments